# Azure storage API for common REST API Error codes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

This may be silly question but I need to find the C# Azure Storage Exception API that wrap “Common REST API Error codes” https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179357.aspx.

Say if it is specific exception on a table operation then we can check error code against “Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableErrorCodeStrings”

I have functionality that wrap creation of Table/Blob/Queue operation in a single method and checking an error type ResourceAlreadyExists while exception handling.

I see this error code ResourceAlreadyExists in Azure Storage Common REST API Error codes as per the documentation but not able to find the  corresponding C# Azure Storage API.

Please let me know if you have some insight into this or how can I find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading too literally into the REST API documentation. :)  Here are the strings for resources that already exist.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.Protocol.BlobErrorCodeStrings.BlobAlreadyExists;
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.Protocol.QueueErrorCodeStrings.QueueAlreadyExists;
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableErrorCodeStrings.TableAlreadyExists;
```

So, you will need to check for the appropriate one depending on which Azure storage resource you are working with at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Those error codes are located in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.StorageErrorCodeStrings` class. Please see the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.shared.protocol.storageerrorcodestrings.aspx) and the source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Shared/Protocol/StorageErrorCodeStrings.cs).

However, please note that these constants are simply set to the error code strings defined in the REST API documentation.